# get point count after appling filter on layer

Tags: filter, count, layer, mapbox-gl

i have layer like this with filter on propertice over a source with cluster enabled in mapbox-gl last version, after that i want to cacluate circle redius based on number of features in this cluster with that filter, but it seems to be undefined and not works, what i tried and have in mind like below:

```
...
filter:["==","property","value"]
paint:{
...,
circle-radius:["*",["get","point_count"],10]
}
```

as you can see i used expression to get number of points, but didnt worked, also tried clusterPropertice of source but it seems can't access them after custom filter